# Kohana make View::factory('/foo/bar') hit bar in foo class

Tags: php, view, kohana

My issue is that Kohana only renders the view. When I

`View::factory('/foo/bar')` in Controller_Other, it doesn't hit Controller_Foo first. I want it to hit the controller, then render the view.

```
class Controller_Other extends Controller_Template {
    public $template = 'main';
    public function action_index() {
        $this->template->body = View::factory('/foo/bar');
    }
}
```

How would I get it to run through the controller first:

```
class Controller_Foo extends Controller_Template {
    public function action_bar() {
        $this->myVar = 'foo';
    }
}
```

so that in the view, `$myVar` is always set in `views/foo/bar.php` when I call it from some other `View::factory()`?

Edit:

there must be a cleaner way than forcing `action_bar` to render its own view to string then going:

```
$foo = new Controller_Foo($this->request, $this->response);
$this->template->body = $foo->action_bar();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing - want to bind global view variable or do an internal request.
Anyway, here are the examples for both cases:

**bind global view variable**

```
class Controller_Other extends Controller_Template {
    public $template = 'main';

    public function action_index() {
      View::bind_global('myVar', 'foo'); 
      //binds value by reference, this value will be available in all views. Also you can use View::set_global();

      $this->template->body = View::factory('/foo/bar');
    }
```

}

**do an internal request**

this is 'foo/bar' action

```
class Controller_Foo extends Controller_Template {

     public function action_bar() {
        $myVar = 'foo';
        $this->template->body = View::factory('/foo/bar', array('myVar' => $myVar);
     }
}



class Controller_Other extends Controller_Template {
    public $template = 'main';
    public function action_index() {
         $this->template->body = Request::factory('foo/bar')->execute()->body();
         //by doing this you have called 'foo/bar' action and put all its output to curent requests template body
    }
}
```

Comment: The internal request looks like what i'm going for. I just want action_bar to be its own thing so that every time I render that view, I don't have to set myVar somewhere else. Btw, is $this->myVar right? shouldn't it just be $myVar? Anywho, you totally solved my problem. this is much cleaner than making a new controller object and calling the method.

Comment: Yes, `$this->myVar` should be `$myVar`, thanks for pointing it out for me. :) Edited my answer. Glad I could help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should always pass $myVar variable to view before render it like

```
public function action_index() {
    $this->template->body = View::factory('/foo/bar')->set('myVar', 'foo');
}
```

In other controller you should set it again because View is just a temlate. If you plan to use the same view in different places of script you can assign View instance to some variable and use it somewhere like:

```
public function action_index() {
    $this->view = View::factory('/foo/bar')->set('myVar', 'foo');

    $this->template->body = $this->view ;
}

public function action_bar() {
    $this->template->head = $this->view ;
}
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot that in my example.. i have action_bar in my code and when I go `$this->myVar`, `$myVar` is not defined in the view.